# Why am I getting random outputs from this string to char conversion?

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm just trying to do a string conversion to char (more precisely char*) but for no reason, I got different outputs if I run the code on codeBlocks or in my project. So on codeBlocks, I run this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string stlstring = "abc";
    std::cout << stlstring << std::endl;
    char* writable = new char[stlstring.size() + 1];
    std::copy(stlstring.begin(), stlstring.end(), writable);
    writable[stlstring.size()] = '\n';
    std::cout << writable ;
}
```

I got this output : [image]

And in my project, I run the same lines but in an event handler :

```
void RePROGUIUser::applyOptions(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    std::string stlstring = "abc";
    std::cout << stlstring << std::endl;
    char* writable = new char[stlstring.size() + 1];
    std::copy(stlstring.begin(), stlstring.end(), writable);
    writable[stlstring.size()] = '\n';
    std::cout << writable;
}
```

Output :[image]

So I have to push a button on my GUI for that to happen but it really shouldn't change anything (and I was skeptical about putting the wxWidget tag here).

Any idea someone ?

Comment: You don't need to allocate new char pointer to do this in c++. You can simply create a new string object, assign the current one to the new one in the new one constructor, and use the `+=` operator to add the char `'\n'`: `std::string stlstring2(stlstring); stlstring2 += '\n'; std::cout << stlstring2;`

Comment: @KorelK this is just a demo code. His real intent is something else. He should be probably using `stlstring.c_str()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), means anything is possible. Note that the [null terminator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) is `'\0'` but not `'\n'`. So change

```
writable[stlstring.size()] = '\n';
```

to

```
writable[stlstring.size()] = '\0';
```

Comment: the kind of bug you reread a hundred times before facepalming.